# unable to connect to ethernet in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have HP Pavilion g6-2201ax laptop. I was working with live usb. But ubuntu detects ethernet connection but before establishing connection it gets disconnected. I have realtek RTL8168 PCIe controller.

This is the info I got over the Internet:

```
Integrated 10/100 BASE-T Ethernet LAN. 
Hardware ID Ethernet Controller 
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&SUBSYS_184AEC103C&REV_05 
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&SUBSYS_184AEC103C 
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&CC_020000 
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&CC_0200
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I have realtek RTL8168 driver

Comment: What do you get when you type this command is Terminal? `sudo dhclient eth0`

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

This is caused by during the installation of Ubuntu, they where unable to automatically grab you're wireless adapter. These hardware id's you see are Vendors and Devices, these Vendors and Devices may be hard to find for a Linux distribution as you're laptop/notebook was designed for a Windows OS. Most manufactures will not provide Linux Distribution drivers for there products.

**Solution**

The only solution I can see for you is to search around in places like PCI Database or google, I can see that you have Internet connection and if that is caused from you being on a different personal computer, you can simply copy it to a USB Key/Fash Drive or burn the files to a CD/DVD.

**Links:**

http://www.pcidatabase.com/

http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/

These are all places to search for you're driver and there are thousands more all across the Internet.